# Time Discretizations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I wanted to know what I will have in third semester of numeric differential equations and at beginning I found this exercise:

> For what $a$ and $b$ the Time Discretizations: $$y_{n+3}+ay_{n+2}+by_{n+1}+ \frac{1}{2} y_{n}=3hf_{n+2}$$
> have maximal order? Test the stability and strong stability for the parameters giving max order.

And that was at first sight after a small amount of theory. I tried expand it to Taylor series and group terms but i don't know what next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the structure it would make sense to center the expansion around the index $n+2$. Then you get from the Taylor expansion of $y(x+h)+ay(x)+by(x-h)+\frac12(y-2h)$ the equation
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
&y+hy'+\frac{h^2}2y''+\frac{h^3}6y'''+...\\
+&ay\\
+&b\left(y-hy'+\frac{h^2}2y''-\frac{h^3}6y'''+...\right)\\
+&\frac12\left(y-2hy'+2h^2y''-\frac{4h^3}3y'''+...\right)
\end{aligned}\right\}
=3hy'
$$
As you then did, collect similar terms and set like terms equal on both sides. Then one finds from $y,y'$ that
\begin{align}
1+a+b+\frac12&=0\\
1-b-1&=3
\end{align}
so that $b=-3$, $a=\frac32$, and the terms in $y''$ may cancel. If they do, the (local, truncation) order is $2$. This increases to $3$ if also the terms for $y'''$ cancel.

To explore the stability, apply the method to $y'=f(t,y)=\lambda y$ with $Im(\lambda)\le0$.